# Android - Firebase Authentication not working with Email/Password setup

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

So, I have my Firebase project setup, and all plugins that should be needed in the build.gradle (I quintuple checked). However, when I run my app and try to run the following method:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

It does not work and I constantly get something - which I will show below - in the log, and a notification manager popping up saying "Channel not found." I am not using a Notification Manager, but I believe it is done deep within the Android Runtime environment.

This method is called after the user types in the username and password in a GUI, and uses the method above to try to create a connection with my firebase project.

```
1-12 01:36:17.181 6593-6593/com.example.sarah.whosthere I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] No Fallback module; NOT setting up for lazy initialization 
11-12 01:37:50.967 6593-6593/com.example.sarah.whosthere W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
11-12 01:37:51.140 1681-3474/system_process E/NotificationService: No Channel found for pkg=com.example.sarah.whosthere, channelId=null, id=10436, tag=null, opPkg=com.example.sarah.whosthere, callingUid=10085, userId=0, incomingUserId=0, notificationUid=10085, notification=Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x110 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
```

Also, in debug mode, during this method call I get a "no such instance field" error for my mAuth variable, which is set to an instance of FirebaseAuth. I tried looking this up, but what I have found and tried does not seem relevant towards my case.

If anyone has any reasons why this method would not be doing anything, I would appreciate the help as I have been banging my head against the wall for the past 4 hours trying to figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** I got this working by changing the version from 11.6.0 down to 10.2.6 for all firebase services, including google play.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem when calling signInWithEmailAndPassword().  Not really an answer, but I think that this has come about since the upgrade to Firebase 11.6.0  Downgrading to 11.4.2 seems to remove the warning messages.

Comment: It's related to Google Play services. Make sure you have the version in the emulator <= to what you have in your gradle.build file.

Comment: Hi - could you expand please?  I am referencing play services 11.6.0 in my build.gradle file e.g.     'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'  Looking at the Play Store in the device that I am running my App on, it says it is version 8.3.73.U.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I had 11.6.0 for all version, but I actually had to downgrade all the versions. I went from 11.4.2 down to 10.2.6. I think 11 is not cooperating  with the emulator...


In the build.gradle file I changed it to the following and it worked:


'compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6'
'compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Issue here, after updating the Google Play Store it works like a charm. I hope it will work for you too

Comment: For me, it is very close to this. My solution was actually related to Google Play, but I had to make it less than or equal to the emulator version as I had it as newer than the emulator

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I found out that the emulator was offline for some reason, so i just closed the emulator and tried again.